# Get session from curl php

Tags: php, session, curl

I am having some trouble getting the actual session of the website, I need to use it later on with a reques.

```
$url="http://blabalbla";
$postdata="pass:123";
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//Le vamos a enviar parámetros posts
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
//Para poder guardar el html
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//Para seguir las redirecciones
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$url_destino=curl_getinfo($handler, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
//Executamos

$response = curl_exec ($handler);
```

I can see that the session is saved in the cookie under PHPSESSID

Comment: If you giving curl call from one server to other session will not be maintained. In that case you need to pass session in curl request and get back that variable back with the curl response. In this manner session will persist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your session cookie saved, but not used. Try to add this option

```
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
```

Comment: So my session will be recorded in the cookie.txt, but how do I retrieve it? opening the file with file_get_content and look for the session?

Comment: No, curl will just read the session data from file you provide in CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. That's why you should point both CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to the same location